# What is the new implementation of app requests dialog in Android Facebook SDK 4.0.1

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I was using old implementation of Facebook **apprequests** dialog in my project like:

```
 Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
 parameters.putString("message","invite friends message...");
 parameters.putString("data","invite friends data...");
 parameters.putString("title","invite friends dialog title...");

 if (facebook != null){
    facebook.dialog(getActivity(), "apprequests", parameters,
        new Facebook.DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                // todo:
            }
        });
  }
```

i have found new implementation in facebook doc. [App Invites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites)

```
appLinkUrl = "my app link...";
previewImageUrl = "my image url...";

if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
    AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
           .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
           .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
           .build();
    AppInviteDialog.show(activity, content);
}
```

Is this right implementation for invite app to friends or any other way? if yes then where would my message and data content would placed.

Or if i am using graph api request like:

```
 String graphPath="/me/apprequests/";
 GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
      accessToken, graphPath, graphCallback);

 Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
 parameters.putString("message","invite friends message...");
 parameters.putString("data","invite friends data...");
 parameters.putString("title","invite friends dialog title...");

 request.setParameters(parameters);
 request.executeAsync();
```

then getting `{"data":[]}` in response and no dialog appears. What would be the correct implementation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution, find below, this is the new implementation of app request dialog in facebook sdk4.

```
    String appLinkUrl = "https://fb.me/...";
    String previewImageUrl = ...;
    final String TAG = "fbv4";

    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
        // start login...
    } else {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(activity.getApplicationContext());
        CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result> facebookCallback= new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result) {
                Log.i(TAG, "MainACtivity, InviteCallback - SUCCESS!" + result.getData());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.i(TAG, "MainACtivity, InviteCallback - CANCEL!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "MainACtivity, InviteCallback - ERROR! " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };

        AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(activity);
        if (appInviteDialog.canShow()) {
            AppInviteContent.Builder content = new AppInviteContent.Builder();
            content.setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl);
            content.setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl);
            AppInviteContent appInviteContent = content.build();
            appInviteDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, facebookCallback);
            appInviteDialog.show(activity, appInviteContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that for the `FacebookCallback` to receive its callbacks, the `CallbackManager` must be added to `onActivityResult` to handle the result: `callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

Answer (score 3):

The old app requests has been renamed [Game Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.3) and is limited to games only.

The [App Invites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites) dialog was just launched recently, and is for all mobile apps (with iOS or Android native apps). With the app invites dialog, you can set a URL (that's app links enabled), you can also add a picture to the invite. However, you cannot prefill with a message, the user must type that in.

Comment: Do you know how to get the selected friends id with the AppInviteDialog?

Comment: You can't. That's by design.

Comment: Yes and it's wrong. Developers should be able to do something else on their end after the Facebook invitations have been sent. For example, I need to create our own invitations, so that I can match the new user with the received invitation.

Comment: You are free to attach tracking IDs to the url that's in the app invite. That's the correct way to track the flow of the invite.